# Why do R if statments have to be in this format?

Tags: r, if-statement

beginner to R and programming in general. Currently taking a beginner's course and was just wondering why an if statment had to be in this format:

```
if (nrow(recent_grads) > 1000) { 
    data_size <- "Large" 
    } else {
        data_size <- "Small"
    }
```

where the { and } characters have to be on seperate lines, as opposed to something more simple such as:

```
if (nrow(recent_grads) > 1000) { data_size <- "Large" }
  else {data_size <- "Small”}
```

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Hi @GildedCrowEscapee, I think if you use case 2, your line will stop at the end of if statement. It won't understand you have the `else` one. If you have single if-else statement, you can remove `{ }`.

Comment: It depends on which `{` and `}` you are talking about. It's not that each code block has to have the opening and closing braces on different lines; it's that the `else` needs to be on the same line as the closing `}` for the block for which it is the `else` clause for. It's just how the R parser was designed. It actually can be a tricky problem when designing your own programming language.